# Should a repository handle default instances?

Tags: architecture, repository-pattern

I am working on a wrapper for IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings on Windows Phone...

One of the reasons for this is to cut down on the amount of if (x == null) code that is strewn about. From what I gather with my own usage is that if I ask for an entity from a repository and it is not there I am going to go create a default instance of it anyway.

What I was wondering is, would it be a bad idea to return a default instance of an entity if no entity is found? If so how should this happen?

Should I allow the user to pass in the default instance? maybe a factory?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should not create default instances if there are none. At least not for an `Get` method.

As for entity creation, I always include a `Create` method in my repositories (with arguments that correspond to the mandatory information).

> One of the reasons for this is to cut down on the amount of if (x == null) code that is strewn about

A repository will not fix that. Repositories is just a way to abstract away the data source. They should not include any other logic (Single responsibility principle).

You might want to add a layer (class) between the repository and all your usages today to get those null checks in one place.